# TOR Error permission issue

Tags: permissions, software-installation, tor

I've tried reinstalling, updating, and removing and then reinstalling.

Nothing seems to work. See screenshot below:

[image]

the output of `gedit /home/skynet/.tor-browser-en/LOG` (The installation log) is:

```
/usr/bin/tor-browser-en.sh: Your version in /home/skynet/.tor-browser-en is outdated or you do not have installed tor-browser-en yet.
/usr/bin/tor-browser-en.sh: Extracting files to /home/skynet/.tor-browser-en/INSTALL.
tar (child): /opt/tor-browser-en/tor-browser-linux64-3.6.2_en-US.tar.xz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see (judging from the folder name and path) you're trying to install Tor Browser from the WebUpd8 Tor Browser PPA. There's a bug in the PPA package which I will fix in a few minutes. So in about 30minutes-1hour, use the following commands to update Tor Browser

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tor-browser
```

Then it should work.

Comment: Good job,@alin. It is working perfectly.